# How to ignore a CloudFlare warning with HttpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, post, httpwebrequest, cloudflare, httpwebresponse

Here i do a Post request and i know the address (i am not the owner) and it is not malicious, I just want to Post the request and get the desired response.

Web request code:

```
HttpWebRequest oHTTP = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://some-random-website.com/");
string data = Uri.EscapeDataString(parameters);

oHTTP.Method = "POST";
oHTTP.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
oHTTP.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 9; WOW64; rv:38.0) Firefox:40.1";
oHTTP.ContentLength = parameters.Length;

using (Stream stream = oHTTP.GetRequestStream())
   stream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(parameters), 0, parameters.Length);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)oHTTP.GetResponse();
string oReceived = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream() ?? throw new InvalidOperationException()).ReadToEnd();
```

Response title: 
*Warning: Suspected Phishing Site Ahead!*

Then there is a button that says:
*Dismiss this warning and enter site*

So my question is how can i ignore this warnings and post my request successfully? Should i change my `UserAgent`?

**Note1:** I use *Fiddler* to inspect both request and response header and content.

**Note2:** I have done the same thing in AutoIt but it uses `WinHttp` and there is no issue on this website.

Comment: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170096-How-do-I-turn-off-the-Cloudflare-Captcha-challenge-page-

Comment: @JohnB I don't have access to the server and security dashboard but i know the site and i am okay with the page.